# How to insert custom value in dialup.conf freeradius sql query?

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, radius, freeradius

how I can add custom value to raddacct table in freeradius?
For example, I need add 'groupname' for user activity log.

As I understant it can be done by matching usergroup in pre-selection from database and insert into needed query. But I still bad know *nix system and scripting for that.

There is a code:

```
accounting_start_query = " \
      INSERT INTO ${acct_table1} \
        (acctsessionid,    acctuniqueid,     username, \
         realm,            nasipaddress,     nasportid, \
         nasporttype,      acctstarttime,    acctstoptime, \
         acctsessiontime,  acctauthentic,    connectinfo_start, \
         connectinfo_stop, acctinputoctets,  acctoutputoctets, \
         calledstationid,  callingstationid, acctterminatecause, \
         servicetype,      framedprotocol,   framedipaddress, \
         acctstartdelay,   acctstopdelay,    xascendsessionsvrkey) \
      VALUES \
        ('%{Acct-Session-Id}', '%{Acct-Unique-Session-Id}', '%{SQL-User-Name}', \
         '%{Realm}', '%{NAS-IP-Address}', '%{NAS-Port}', \
         '%{NAS-Port-Type}', '%S', NULL, \
         '0', '%{Acct-Authentic}', '%{Connect-Info}', \
         '', '0', '0', \
         '%{Called-Station-Id}', '%{Calling-Station-Id}', '', \
         '%{Service-Type}', '%{Framed-Protocol}', '%{Framed-IP-Address}', \
         '%{%{Acct-Delay-Time}:-0}', '0', '%{X-Ascend-Session-Svr-Key}')"
```